# What's it called when you use "with" in a list, but it's not clear which part of the sentence "with" refers to?

Tags: grammar, lists, modifiers

This has been driving me mad lately, I'm editing a lot of copy and this is the most common error I've noticed. Here's an example:

"Amenities at the inn include a traditional pub with a menu consisting of locally sourced ingredients, as well as bike storage."

Because they've said that it's a traditional pub with a menu, it's unclear whether the menu has bike storage, the traditional pub has bike storage or whether the inn has bike storage.

What's the best way of handling sentences that list things without becoming ambiguous and unclear?

Comment: I don't think it is ambiguous. "Amenities include a menu as well as a bike storage.*

Comment: @Josh61 Not sure if you're making a funny here. The restaurant itself does not have bike storage, the bike storage belongs to the series of objects related to the inn itself.

Comment: I agree with Josh, I had to search for the ambiguity - though, as always, now I can't miss it, so this might be an editor's malady. Although I must say that I read it as the amenities are part of the Inn experience.

Comment: Wait, just to clarify here, did you think that the restaurant had bike storage? That's not the intended meaning at all. The inn has a restaurant and bike storage.

Comment: Yes, that is clear..you are just saying that "amenities at the ***INN*** include a pub with a menu as well as a bike storage.

Comment: No, I was saying that I read the intended meaning - bike storage as part of the Inn's offerings - first read.

Comment: This is a classical Attachment Ambiguity. In a right-branching language like English, we can stack up phrases at the end of the sentence, and a final conjunction like the one here has to be attached to some preceding phrase. But which one? The normal case is the noun phrase immediately preceding, but that puts bike storage on the pub menu, along with locally sourced ingredients; so we look up and find _menu_ to conjoin. Attachment ambiguities are very common in writing; they're just as common in speech, but since they're not pronounced or intoned the same, we rarely notice, except in jokes.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, this was the answer I was looking.

Comment: As for how to clarify what goes with what, one way to dispose of the ambiguity is to add em dashes to break out the discussion of the menu. Doing so leaves you with "pub" and "bike storage" in parallel, where (presumably) they belong: "Amenities at the inn include a traditional pub—with a menu consisting of locally sourced ingredients—and bike storage."

Answer (score 1):

"Amenities at the inn include a traditional pub with a menu consisting of locally sourced ingredients. Bike storage is available for cyclists."

Comment: Hey! I'm paying the same room rate as those rotten cyclists. I should get some bike storage too!

Comment: @Dan Bron, sod off mate, I just work here!

Comment: @Dan Bron, management has just informed me that my services will no longer be required. :-(

Comment: Alright, let's head down to the pub then. Heard they have a lovely locally-sourced Guiness.

Comment: @Dan: You should be okay if you go to OP's inn - which, unlike Little Eva's, doesn't explicitly restrict use of the bike storage facilities to *cyclists*. Many of us ***ex-cyclists*** like to strap our now-unused bike to the car when we go on hotel breaks, just so we have an excuse to hang around the bike shed for a chat and a cigarette.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, posers, all.

Comment: @Dan Bron, am I to understand that *have a love* = a lovely locally-sourced Guiness?

Comment: @Little Eva: Even though I no longer cycle myself, I think It's okay to wear my lycra cycling pants when socializing with those who still do. But I agree - those guys who wear leather posing pouches just to go for a chat and fag round the bike shed are definitely posers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, completely reasonable. Sadly, I'm limited nowadays to a stationary bike - but I still wear the full drag, including helmet! ;-)

Comment: @LittleEva You dress in drag? Huh, I love these little getting-to-know-you chats ;)

Comment: @Dan Bron, please translate, *have a love*.

Comment: Are we [bike-shedding](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bikeshedding) *here?* :)

Comment: @LittleEva In general, when a system permits editing, you should pay attention to the final, edited form of the post (comment, article, whatever). If a post is edited, that means the author identified something wrong with his own post, and corrected it. Which means the prior forms were erroneous and transitional and should be ignored. In this case, my big dumb thumb hit "send" when I intended to hit spacebar, cutting me off in the middle of typing "having a lovely locally-sourced Guiness". But those specifics are beside the point; don't concern yourself with anything except the final state.

Comment: @Dan Bron, oh that's funny (haha), I thought you had deleted the *hava a love* comment and that I was looking at an entirely different and additional articulation. That's right Dan, you're probably using your mobile. Anyway, thanks for the pithy fun. :-)

Comment: Amazing @FumbleFingers what can be found at the UD!